# Installing odepkg in Octave

Tags: octave

I downloaded odepkg package from the internet. I saved it in the same folder as Octave GUI, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtHEH.png):

[image: Octave folders]

I tried following the instructions but I don't know which file to use. I can't find any .gz file, as in example. pkg install odepkg returns warning: file odepkg does not exist

I'm really sorry if this is a stupid question but I still hope you can help me... Any general advice on how to handle similar problems is also appreciated. I'm a newbie in programming/numerical computation and would love to learn, but there are some basics, like the one I'm asking about, that I can't find info on.

After following the second method:
[image: After following the second method] (if I understood it correctly)

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
 pkg install -forge odepkg
```

If that doesn't work download the .tar.gz package file from octave forge. https://octave.sourceforge.io/download.php?package=odepkg-0.8.5.tar.gz

And save the file somewhere and in octave (for example c:\octave), In octave, CD to the directorywhere you saved the file  (if it isn't the directory octave is currently showing):

```
cd 'c:\octave\'
```

then run:

```
pkg install odepkg-0.8.5.tar.gz
```

After installing the package, don't forget to load the package before using its functions:

```
pkg load odepkg
```

Comment: What does CD to the directory mean?

Comment: 峔檘error: get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection
error: called from
    get_forge_pkg at line 77 column 7
    get_forge_download at line 26 column 12
    pkg at line 393 column 29

Comment: Internet connection is ok, obviously

Comment: sourceforge changed to using https somewhat recently, which I believe broke older versions of octave for pkg install -forge.  Use the second method with the manual download.

Comment: I did use the second method. I downloaded odepkg-0.8.5.tar.gz from the link you gave me, saved it to octave folder (did not extract it) and followed your instructions... I added a screenshot to the bottom of my original question. And thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: @nunca13 Do not include the `-forge` as that will attempt to connect to the Octave repos online.  Remove `-forge` in your call and it'll work since you've downloaded the package manually.

Comment: @lostbard Remove the `-forge` string from the command as you are no longer using Octave-Forge as the source of the package.  The package was downloaded manually.  I've decided to edit your answer and gave you a subsequent upvote.